# adding a web form aspx page to WCF project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

i need to build a project that has a `WCF .svc` service and some web pages in the same c# project. Is there any problem in doing this? if I create a project of type WCF project using Visual `studio 2010`, it lets me add `web forms` to it. Once I publish to IIS, i should be able to hit the `.svc url and .aspx urls` seamlessly under the same root url.

Any problem in doing this in the long run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no problems. This ought to work.

If you want to use MVC then it's probably better to start from that template and add SVC components.

Do think about authentication and authorization upfront.

Comment: Thank you for your input. what do you mean by authentication and authorization? the aspx pages will be accessing the .svc service to display some data. the .svc service can also be accessed without going through the pages. Clients will be passing in a key and some other data to identify themselves but thats controlled by the application. Is there anything else i need to worry about?

Comment: If your website is open it's all OK. If you use Windows-Auth you might have problems.